# Positionning button from bottom screen

Tags: android, button, screen

I am doing some XML for an android app.

I have images, text, and button in my view.

I used a Linear layout, but I think it's not what I need.

I would like to set my last button to 80 dp from the bottom screen. Regardless the smartphone and the size of the screen.
I want my button to be at 80 dp from the bottom of all device.

I have no idea how to do it if someone can help me it could be cool!

I tried with a LinearLayout but i think i can't do it.

Now I'm trying with a constraintLayout but I'm not sure it will work.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of the ways to achieve your goal using Relative layout as parent:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Bottom Button"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a `RelativeLayout` and *`layout_alignParentBottom`* take a look at this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="textview1"/>


<ImageView
    android:layout_width="20dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textview1"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:text="Button"
    android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Relative layout as parent layout not Linear Layout after that use this code 
ADD Views inside this Relative Layout whatever you want to add like Textview etc.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button at bottom"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution with constraint layout.

I'm using  app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf to align my button to the bottom of my screen then i use a marginBottom. Thanks for all for your response, i will try it with a relative layout :)

Comment: I have tested and your solution with relativeLayout work aswell. thanks guys